# Using my own SSL certificate with Google Cloud Run (fully managed) for SSL pinning

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-run

I want to pin the certificate of my fully managed Google Cloud Run cluster.

I can pin the Google generated SSL certificate, but I don't know if I can rely on them to keep the same certificate until it expires AND I can't prepare the client for the future SSL certificates they will generate because I'm not aware of them before they are automatically installed by Google.

In other words, their software may regenerate it occasionally for optimizations or some other internal logic.

Are there any other solutions (not including signing each response)?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you concerned with the SSL certificate changing (being updated)? SSL Certificates are validated, they are not "binary" compared.

Comment: Because a new certificate gets a new pinning and I have to update the client at least a month before with the new certificate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't be possible until Cloud Run supports [Cloud HTTP(S) Load Balancers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/), which in turn support self-managed certificates.

Comment: This now works, and is possible. You can map custom domains to your Cloud Run Services.  To do so: on the Left Hand side navbar, click Cloud Run, then Click "Domain Mappings".  At the top, click "Add Mapping". You will be guided.  You'll need to verify the domain, kinda like ACME, with a DNS TXT record.

Comment: @Cheeso this will just do the domain mapping. Not the custom SSL certificates.

Comment: So there's no way to use SSL without adding the extra layer/cost of a load balancer?