# Do I need SSL/TLS for a gRPC API server?

Tags: go, ssl, cloud, grpc, google-cloud-run

I want to create my API using gPRC. It should not be a public (in terms of user friendly, it will still be publicly reachable) API, however my frontend will be built on top of the gRPC backend. Since the frontend is a normal website, my question now is regarding the SSL/TLS encryption that gRPC forces me to do. The problem I got now is that this means, that every client has to get my certificate to use for encryption. In the documentation and examples they all assume that the client simply has access to the folder where my server stores its certificates, but this won't be the case in my environment. Furthermore it is also described that I could store it inside the /etc/... folder of the other host, but my setup won't include other hosts, it is just the gRPC server and then many clients from my js frontend application.

Should I create some kind of endpoint on my frontend hosting server, through which the frontend can download the certificate and then instantiate the connection to the gRPC backend?

Postman somehow works without explicitly telling em the certificate location. Is there some kind of wellknown endpoint in the gRPC through which postman gets the certificate?

I will be hosting on Google Cloud Run which has a SSL/TLS encryption already in place (it will encrypt until the data is in my container), will this one be enough for me so i am able to create the gRPC server insecurely?

Comment: "but my setup wont include other hosts, it is just the gRPC server and then many clients from my js frontend application" -- The clients from your JS frontend applications _are the other hosts_

Comment: It will probably be easier, and certainly safer, to use gRPC as intended. Setting up certs is not that difficult these days, especially with services like [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: Yes, you are right, poor wording. I can't install my certificate on the /etc/...  paths of my clients, since i am not controlling their environment

Comment: gRPC does not force the use of TLS. Use [insecure.NewCredential](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.56.1/credentials/insecure#NewCredentials) with grpc.Creds when creating the server if you don't want to use it (and there is an equivalent DialOption for clients, although if I understand correctly that won't be necessary because you are connecting through a TLS-enabled proxy).

Comment: "I will be hosting on Google Cloud Run which has a ssl/tls encryption already in place (it will encrypt until the data is in my container)." This can't be true if you don't have your own certificate.

Comment: i know about the insecure version of setting it up, but i feel like thats not the right way.

Comment: It is actually true, if you host on cloud run they will encrypt the data with their own certificates, however since there is the option to make an e2e connection for the cloud run instance this encryption will be omitted, which means in my understanding, that i have to care about the enryption again

Comment: which also would not be a problem, if there is a way to enable the client to pull the ceritifcate. But i dont know if that is the way to do it

Comment: There is no way to do that, otherwise the authenticity part of TLS wouldn't work. However, you may be able to get a certificate for free from Let's Encrypt. Those will be trusted by pretty much all clients. To get a certificate from LE you need control over the DNS records for the hostname clients connect to, or over the webroot of the web server (which you presumably have). I don't know how you would use them with Google Cloud Run. [Seems you'll need to pay for a load balancer to make that work.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61351427/603316)

Comment: Just feel its worth noting that if your client is a browser (an assumption based on "frontend is a normal website"), then you will be using [gRPC-Web](https://grpc.io/blog/state-of-grpc-web/) because browser APIs lack functionality needed for gRPC. Also browser security models don't generally allow you to use your own certificates when establishing https connections.